# FirebaseUI RecyclerView random items added to listitems

Tags: android, firebase

When a button is pressed, a dialog appears asking user for message, with the option of attaching an image (from url). The problem I'm having is once the recyclerview is filled with enough items to scroll, when the user scrolls quickly for some reason random images start popping up in seemingly random list items.

I know the problem has to come from when the image is actually placed into the imageview, since I can tell the link is added to the firebase db just fine.

When the image link is submitted, it's sent to /posts/$uid/$post-id in a HashMap. Kind of like this:

```
final Map<String, String> postMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
imagebutton.setOnClickListener((view) -> {
AlertDialog.Builder = new...
LayoutInflater in = ...
View dialogLayout = ...inflate(r.layout...., null);
build.setView(dialogLayout);
EditText imgText = ...
Button submit = ...

AlertDialog a = build.create();
submit.setOnClickListener((View) -> {
...
    postMap.put("imgLink", imgText.getText().toString());
    a.dismiss();
...
urlDialog.show();
```

Then a few more items are added to the map and pushed to firebase.

```
Firebase postRef = ref.child("posts").child(auth.getUid());
postMap.put("author", ...);
postMap.put("content", ...);

postRef.push().setValue(postMap);
```

But like I said, I'm almost 100% sure the problem is not in posting the information, just populating the recview

Here's my code for the list itself:

```
RecyclerView feed = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler);
if (ref.getAuth() != null) {
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<TextPost, PostViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<TextPost, PostViewHolder>(TextPost.class, R.layout.list_item, PostViewHolder.class, ref.child("posts").child(uid)) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final PostViewHolder postViewHolder, final TextPost textPost, int i) {
                postViewHolder.content.setText(textPost.getContent());
                postViewHolder.author.setText(textPost.getAuthor());
                postViewHolder.score.setText(textPost.getScore());
                postViewHolder.time.setText(textPost.getTime());

                if (textPost.getImgLink() != null && !textPost.getImgLink().equals("")) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Setting image");
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                final Bitmap pic = bitmapFromUrl(textPost.getImgLink());
                                postViewHolder.img.post(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            postViewHolder.img.setImageBitmap(pic);
                                        }
                                });
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();
                }
...
feed.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I just started learning how to work with worker threads for network activities off the main UI thread so I assume I messed that up? I've gone through the logic over and over in my head and i can't seem to figure out what's going wrong here.

EDIT: I tried using AsyncTask instead of Threads and the problem persists. sos

Comment: I haven't seen this myself, but I expect that your bitmap data comes back when the RecyclerView has already recycled the ViewHolder. If that is indeed the cause, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23432372/listview-shows-wrong-and-duplicates-images, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525999/recyclerview-async-image-loading and probably more from this list: https://www.google.com/webhp?#q=recyclerview%20reuses%20viewholder%20with%20wrong%20bitmap

Comment: Thanks, man that did the trick! Just had to set the ImageView to null before assigning it.

Comment: Goog to hear. I didn't actually know which one would solve it. Thanks for confirming and self-answering.

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do was set the ImageView drawable to null before populating the ImageView.

Like this:

```
@Override
protected void populateViewHolder(final ViewHolder v, final Object o, int i) {
    //populate views
    v.content.setText("...");
    //Set imageview to null
    v.imageview.setImageDrawable(null);*

    if (o.getImageLink() != null && !o.getImageLink.equals("")) {
        // Start AsyncTask to get image from link and populate imageview
        new DownloadImageTask().execute(o.getImgLink(), v.imageview); 
    }
}
```